# Can I change the acceleration for my trackpoint on Linux/X11?

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad t450s with the physical trackpoint buttons. It uses the synaptics driver and shows up like this in `xinput(1)`:

```
⎡   Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I'd like to change the acceleration of the trackpoint pointing device--the red nub that folks refer to with more creative names. I haven't found anything in `synclient(1)` nor `synaptics(4)` about this (although maybe I'm not searching for the right term). How do I increase the acceleration of the trackpoint, such that it moves faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration). You can use `xset m # #` command to set acceleration and threshold.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you! I would have thought that the settings in `xset(1)` for the mouse would affect the touchpad, not the trackpoint, but some experimentation shows that they are indeed specific to the trackpoint. Now comes the fun part of experimenting with the possible values to find that Goldilocks value.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method of `xset` didn’t work for me.

So I used `xinput` in the following way:

```
# list all input devices and search for id of the trackpoint (TPPS)
DEVICE_ID=$(xinput list | sed -n '/TPPS/s%.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*%\1%p')

# search for the property number of the acceleration speed
ACCEL_SPEED=$(xinput list-props "$DEVICE_ID" | sed -n '/Accel\ Speed\ (/s%.*Accel Speed (\([0-9]\+\)).*%\1%p')

# set new acceleration speed -1 (= disable acceleration)
xinput set-prop "$DEVICE_ID" "$ACCEL_SPEED" -1
```

### Permanent change

If you want to make that change permanent you could put those three lines in one of your startup/autostart files, e.g. `~/.xsessionrc`.

#### Permanent change for Xmonad

Or in my case (I am using *Xmonad*) I put those three lines in a small script and added a line `spawn "disable-trackpoint-acceleration.sh"` calling that script from within my `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file.

([Source](http://granitosaurus.rocks/disable-thinkpad-acceleration.html))